# Magento product grid block code breaks PHP after only the first product is displayed

Tags: php, magento

I wish to display all products on the home page. The following block seems to have the desired effect:

```
    {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

**Except** that HTML output breaks after the first product in the grid. No subsequent products, sidebars or footers are included.

What is missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide code of catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm a total amateur and can't find the code in question... the best I can provide you is a link to [the site itself](http://locallegendsrecords.com/). Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Category cassettes does only seem to have one product.

Comment: There are two products in the overarching 'default' category, which is what I hoped to display. The output from the block does say "2 Item(s)", but then stops displaying (anything at all, including the footer) after the link to the first product.

The page source just stops...

Comment: It's not usual to use the overarching default category. Make another category like 'all products' and attach all products to this and try again.

Comment: I have done so but unfortunately to no avail - still the same problem. Thanks for your help, though! Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Posted my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. The full solution is detailed in [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9), which I only found tonight. The problem is a consequence of changes to the rwd template in Magento 1.9.

Inspecting the error log - which **is not** stored where *Configuration -> Developer -> Log Settings* claimed it was, it gave:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in .../app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 134

By appending the code provided in [the post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9) to three places in the *list.phtml* file, the error is resolved. Subsequent products in the grid now load, as well as the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento admin, add a new category. In the top of the page, you see the category id behind the name, like `Category name (ID: 20)`. To show this category on homepage, use:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="20" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Where the part `category_id="20"` is the category id i mentioned above.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. The new "All Products" category is active and the products correctly assigned. Its ID is "7". However, the problem occurs once again.

Will try again in the morning. Really grateful for your help and for any further suggestions! Thanks.